# Create new elements, simple notification constructor, send data when a notification is dismissed, etc

Tags: javascript

This is not ordinary question but it's also not opinion-based, it's more about the standards and the right way of writing JS code. I admit, I'm a total noob in JavaScript, I do not have experience with this language but since it is necessary for the project I'm working on - I had no other choice but to learn a bit about it :P The most basic of things, took me quite some time so I just want to know if the code is written the right way or not. That way I could understand what I've done wrong and learn from it. The reason I'm asking whether it's right or not, instead of checking it myself is because everything work as it supposed to so I've no idea whether I've done it the right way or at least in a valid way.

My JavaScript code;

```js
if(isMobile) {
 var currentProtocol = window.location.protocol + '\/\/';
 var currentHostname = siteHostname;
 var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
 window.location.href = currentProtocol+mobileHostname+currentPath;
}

function goBack() {

 window.history.back()

}

$('a[aria-controls="*"]').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
})

$('.close').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
})

$(function (e) {

 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
 $('[aria-controls="*"]').tab('show');

})

function hideCookieNotice() {

 $('#cookie-notice').addClass('hidden');

}

$('#cookie-notice-close').click(function (e) {
 document.cookie='acgcookie=0;path=.'+siteHostname+';expires='+(new Date(+new Date()+157785e6)).toGMTString();
 hideCookieNotice();
})

if (document.cookie.search('acgcookie=0') !== -1) {
 hideCookieNotice();
}

var elementHelper = {
 
 /* ==========================================================================
  Block Types and Elements
 ========================================================================== */
 notificationDiv: '<div class=\"side-notifications\">',


 /* ==========================================================================
  Buttons
 ========================================================================== */
 closeButton: '<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\"><span class=\"fa fa-close\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span></button>',


 /* ==========================================================================
  Closing Tags
 ========================================================================== */
 closeDiv: '</div>',


 /* ==========================================================================
  Icon Types
 ========================================================================== */

 icon: function (type) {

  function newIcon(type) {

   if (type == 'info')
   {
    return 'info-circle';
   }

   else if (type == 'info2')
   {
    return 'info-circle2';
   }

   else
   {
    return 'Error';
   }

   return type;

  }

  theIcon = newIcon(type);

  return iconConstruct(theIcon);

  function iconConstruct(icon) {

   return '<i class=\"fa fa-' + icon +'\"></i>';

  }
 }
}

function newNotification(outputMessage) {

 html = elementHelper.notificationDiv + elementHelper.closeButton + elementHelper.icon('info') + ' ' + outputMessage + '.' + elementHelper.closeDiv;
 $(html).hide().appendTo('#side-block').fadeIn('slow');

}

function printLog(outputLog) {

 console.log(outputLog);

}

function sendDismiss(e) { 

 var form_data = '';
 var outputMessage = '';
 var outputLog = '';

 form_data = {
  username: userName,
  csrfToken: csrf,
  type: e[0],
  id: e[1],
  is_ajax: '1'
 };

 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'test.php',
  data: form_data,
  success: function (response) {

   if (response == 'success') {
    outputMessage = '<strong>Success:</strong> username=' + form_data['username'] + ', csrf=' + form_data['csrfToken'] + ', type=' + form_data['type'] + ', id=' + form_data['id']; 
    outputLog = 'Success';
    newNotification(outputMessage);
    printLog(outputLog);
   }

   else if (response == '') {
    outputMessage = 'Empty';
    outputLog = 'Empty response';
    newNotification(outputMessage);
    printLog(outputLog);
   }

   else {
    outputMessage = response;
    outputLog = response;
    newNotification(outputMessage);
    printLog(outputLog);
   }

  },
  error: function () {

   outputMessage = 'Error';
   outputLog = 'No response';
   newNotification(outputMessage);
   printLog(outputLog);

  }

 }); 

 return false;

}

function changeLang(siteLang) { 

 document.cookie='acglang='+siteLang+';path=.'+siteHostname+';expires='+(new Date(+new Date()+157785e6)).toGMTString();

 var form_data = '';
 var outputMessage = '';
 var outputLog = '';

 form_data = {
  username: userName,
  csrfToken: csrf,
  lang: siteLang,
  is_ajax: '1'
 };

 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'test.php',
  data: form_data,
  success: function () {

   outputLog = 'Successfully changed site language to ' + siteLang;
   printLog(outputLog);

  },
  error: function () {

   outputMessage = 'Error, failed to change site language to ' + siteLang + '.<br />Please contact Support and report this error.';
   outputLog = 'Error';
   newNotification(outputMessage);
   printLog(outputLog);

  }

 });  

 return false;

}

function closeIt(e){

 $( this ).parent().fadeOut( "slow" );

}

$("#side-block").on('click', "button.close", closeIt);

$(function (e){

 $(".close.send-data").click(function(n){

  var e = new Array($(this).data("type"), $(this).data("id"));
  sendDismiss(e);

 });

})
```

I did not include the actual mobile device detection because I did not write it myself, I found it on StackOverflow.

Also in my HTML doc, the following variables are set;

```js
  var siteHostname  =  "{siteHostname}";
  var mobileHostname  =  "{$mobileHostname}";
  var userName   =  "{userName}";
  var csrf    =  "{}";
```

Comment: @CoreModule please do not change the code in your question after some answers have been posted, so as to not invalidate them.

Comment: I understand, sorry.

Comment: No worries, just something to remember :-)

Comment: Again, please do not change the code in your question after some answers have been posted, so as to not invalidate them.

Answer (score 2):

Because the definition of the variables defined with `var` are always hoisted to the top of the function block, it is better to list them in the beginning of the function and not somewhere in between, otherwise it is not easy to see which variable names are *bound* to the current scope  [mdn: var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)).

If your target environment supports `let` you might use that one instead of `var` ([mdn: let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)).

In most cases you want to use the `===` and `!==` operator and not the `==` or `!=`, there are for sure situations where `==` will be ok but most of the time you should use the strict comparison ([Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)).

For `$.ajax` I would use the promise capabilities `.then()` and `.fail()`. The reason I would do that is that you separate the parameter that are used to create the request from the actions that should be don on failure and success.

```
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'test.php',
  data: form_data
})
.then(function() {
  outputLog = 'Successfully changed site language to ' + siteLang;
  printLog(outputLog);
})
.fail(function() {
  outputMessage = 'Error, failed to change site language to ' + siteLang + '.<br />Please contact Support and report this error.';
  outputLog = 'Error';
  newNotification(outputMessage);
  printLog(outputLog);
});
```

Writing `var form_data = '';` and then later directly changing it to:

```
form_data = {
    username: userName,
    csrfToken: csrf,
    type: e[0],
    id: e[1],
    is_ajax: '1'
};
```

Does not make much sense. There it would be better to either not assign anything `var form_data;` or maybe directly write it that way:

```
var form_data = {
    username: userName,
    csrfToken: csrf,
    type: e[0],
    id: e[1],
    is_ajax: '1'
}, 
outputMessage = '',
outputLog = '';
```

You should limit the variable definition to the scope where you use them.
As of that you should move the `outputMessage` and `outputLog` to the `then` and `fail` callback functions, because you only use them inside of them nowhere else.

Make sure that you always define the variables that you use in your functions using `var`, otherwise you will pollute the global/outer scope, which might result in unexpected behaviour:

```
function newNotification(outputMessage) { 
  var html = elementHelper.notificationDiv + elementHelper.closeButton + elementHelper.icon('info') + ' ' + outputMessage + '.' + elementHelper.closeDiv;
  $(html).hide().appendTo('#side-block').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Try to avoid to use the same variable names `e`, here you could just remove the `e` because you don't use it, otherwise it might be mixed with the `var e` you defined inside. A different naming would be even more important if you would use the parameter `e` somewhere.

```
$(function(e) {
  $(".close.send-data").click(function(n) {
    var e = new Array($(this).data("type"), $(this).data("id"));
    sendDismiss(e);
  });
});
```

Keep a consistent way of defining your functions. Within your `icon: function (type) {`  you define `newIcon` at the beginning and `iconConstruct` at the end. In the given code it is is obvious, but this might result problems in larger code.

`newIcon`  has a return statement `return type;` at the end that is never called, because of the `return 'Error';`.

In `sendDismiss` it is not known what `e` is because the name is not self-explaining, especially the  `e[0]`, `e[1]` in combination with the `type`, `id` it can be guessed, but it is still a bad design.

The final rework of the code could then look like this. It for sure can still be made better, but now you have more structure in it:

```
var elementHelper = {
  // Block Types and Elements
  notificationDiv: '<div class="side-notifications">',

  // Buttons
  closeButton: '<button type="button" class="close"><span class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>',

  // Closing Tags
  closeDiv: '</div>',

  // Icon Types
  icon: function(type) {

    function newIcon(type) {
      switch( type ) {
        case 'info':
          return 'info-circle';
        case 'info2':
          return 'info-circle2';
        default:
          return 'Error';//return type; depends on what you original expected 
      }
    }

    function iconConstruct(icon) {
      return '<i class="fa fa-' + icon + '"></i>';
    }

    var theIcon = newIcon(type);

    return iconConstruct(theIcon);
  }
};

// =======    code to be executeded

if (isMobile) {
  redirectMobile( window.location.protocol + '\/\/', 
                  siteHostname,
                  window.location.pathname );
}


$('a[aria-controls="*"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('.close').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  $('[aria-controls="*"]').tab('show');
});

$('#cookie-notice-close').click(function(e) {
  document.cookie = 'acgcookie=0' +
                    ';path=.' + siteHostname +
                    ';expires=' + (new Date(+new Date() + 157785e6)).toGMTString();
  hideCookieNotice();
});

if (document.cookie.search('acgcookie=0') !== -1) {
  hideCookieNotice();
}

$("#side-block").on('click', 'button.close', closeIt);

$(function() {

  $(".close.send-data").click(function(n) {
    var e = {
      type : $(this).data("type"),
      id   : $(this).data("id")
    };

    sendDismiss(e);
  });
});



// =======    function definitions
function redirectMobile(currentProtocol, currentHostname, currentPath) {
  window.location.href = currentProtocol + mobileHostname + currentPath;
}

function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}

function hideCookieNotice() {
  $('#cookie-notice').addClass('hidden');
}

function newNotification(outputMessage) {
  var html = elementHelper.notificationDiv + 
             elementHelper.closeButton +
             elementHelper.icon('info') + ' ' +
             outputMessage +
             '.' +elementHelper.closeDiv;

  $(html)
      .hide()
      .appendTo('#side-block')
      .fadeIn('slow');

}

function printLog(outputLog) {
  console.log(outputLog);
}


function sendDismiss(e) {
  var form_data = {
    username: userName,
    csrfToken: csrf,
    type: e.type,
    id: e.id,
    is_ajax: '1'
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: form_data
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    var outputMessage,
        outputLog;

    if (response === 'success') {
      outputMessage = '<strong>Success:</strong>' + 
                      ' username=' + form_data.username +
                      ', csrf=' + form_data.csrfToken +
                      ', type=' + form_data.type +
                      ', id=' + form_data.id;
      outputLog = 'Success';

      newNotification(outputMessage);
      printLog(outputLog);
    } else if (response === '') {
      outputMessage = 'Empty';
      outputLog = 'Empty response';

      newNotification(outputMessage);
      printLog(outputLog);
    } else {
      outputMessage = response;
      outputLog = response;

      newNotification(outputMessage);
      printLog(outputLog);
    }

  })
  .fail(function() {
    var outputMessage,
        outputLog;

    outputMessage = 'Error';
    outputLog = 'No response';

    newNotification(outputMessage);
    printLog(outputLog);
  });

  return false;
}

function changeLang(siteLang) {
  var form_data = {
    username: userName,
    csrfToken: csrf,
    lang: siteLang,
    is_ajax: '1'
  };

  document.cookie = 'acglang=' + siteLang +
                    ';path=.' + siteHostname +
                    ';expires=' + (new Date(+new Date() + 157785e6)).toGMTString();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: form_data
  })
  .then(function() {
    var outputMessage = '',
        outputLog = 'Successfully changed site language to ' + siteLang;

    printLog(outputLog);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    var outputMessage = 'Error, failed to change site language to ' + siteLang +
                        '.<br />Please contact Support and report this error.',
        outputLog = 'Error';

    newNotification(outputMessage);
    printLog(outputLog);
  });

  return false;
}

function closeIt(e) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative comment.
All the variables declarations are at the beginning of the function except for two cases where they are second to top because it's just easier to read it that way and associate it with the actual code where it's used (refer to the sendDismiss && changeLang functions for more information).

As for "Let", I've never heard of it but I'm definitely going to read about it more a few hours, I've been up for 36hrs so far..
Thank you for the very informative and contributing comment, I appreciate it.

Comment: @CoreModule It was about the `if(isMobile) {` here it looks like that you expect that `currentProtocol` , `currentHostname` and `currentPath` only exist with in the `if`  block but this is not the case, if someone else will review the code then this person needs to check if those variable names are also used outside of the function and if their usage there is valid.

Comment: I've used variables for it to make it cleaner, it's just more organized like this. These three variables are used only within the if statement so far. I think it will be used outside of the statement later on but for now it's just inside of the statement.
Also I've edited the code and added the .then and .fail methods as you pointed out. Thank you :)

Comment: @CoreModule then this is an indication that you want to create a helper function for that. Anyway  `var` statements are not close the the function bounds (normally to the top of the function) will result into hard to maintain and to debug code.

Answer (score 1):

(BTW: please reduce indentation if you post here, the code-view-blocks are quite narrow)

The function `elementHelper` is quite a mess, you should manipulate the DOM-tree directly for everything that is more complex than changing some text somehwere. You can use jquery to do so nad you shoul as you will understand if you take a look at function if you do it by hand (none of the functions listed here are tested):

```
  closeButton: function(){
                 // you can do the whole mess much easier in jquery
                 var button = document.createElement("button");
                 var span = document.createElement("span");
                 var type = document.createAttribute("type");
                 var css = document.createAttribute("class");
                 type.value = "button";
                 css.value = "close";
                 button.setAttributeNode(type);
                 button.setAttributeNode(css);
                 css.value = "fa fa-close";
                 span.setAttribute(css);
                 type = document.createAttribute("aria-hidden");
                 type.value = "true";
                 span.setAttribute(type);
                 button.appendChild(span);
                 return button;
               };
```

You don't want that, or do you? Yes, this all had to be done in the  "good ol' times" old people speak of, which weren't good at all.

The advantage of direct manipulation of the DOM-tree is in one part taht of optimization: the JavaScript engine can pre-optimize and the DOM-parser has no need to parse a string into a DOM-branch *and* link it into the main tree. Another part is debugging: you *will* have typos in long strings and errors in the tree-builder are easier to find than typos in long strings.

The function `icon` is also a bit of a mess, as t.niese correctly noted. A slightly cleaned up version would be e.g.:

```
icon: function(type){
        var newIcon = function(type){
                        if (type == 'info') {
                          return 'info-circle';
                        } else if (type == 'info2') {
                          return 'info-circle2';
                        } else {
                          return 'Error';
                        }
                        return type;
                      };
          var iconConstruct = function(icon){
                                var icon_name = "fa-" + icon;
                                var i = document.createElement("i");
                                var css = document.createAttribute("class");
                                i.setAttribute(css);
                                i.className = "fa "+icon_name;
                                return i;
                             }
          return iconConstruct(newIcon(type));
}
```

but I would contract it into a single function.